# How to delete keys from dictionary by their values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
students = {'palii':('male','170'),
            'Minckach':('male','176'),
            'ddl':('male','180'),
            'Red1ska':('male','188'),
            'Sargeras':('male','185'),
            'Gerus':('female','160'),
            'Liah':('male','183'),
            'Chhekan':('female','182'),
            'Leshega':('male','186'),
            'yurii':('male','187')}
```

I have this dictionary. How can i delete all the females from it and calculate males average height? Maybe there is a function or something that idk?

I tried using `filter()` like

```
newDict = dict(filter(lambda elem: elem[1] == 'male',students.items()))
```

But this is not working.

```
def halfmale(stats): 
    sum = 0
    for key in stats.values():
        sum += float(key)
    half = sum / len(stats)
    print(half)
    for value, key in stats.items():
        if (key+5>half and key-5<half):
            print(value)
```

Python says that promlem is division by zero in this part

Comment: your filter idea would work if it was `elem[1][0]` instead of just `elem[1]` in the lambda or you could do `'male' in elem[1]`

Comment: Beside the point, but [I recommend avoiding `filter(lambda)`](/a/61945553/4518341); use a comprehension instead, i.e. `dict(elem for elem in students.items() if elem[1][0] == 'male')` or `{k:v for k,v in students.items() if v[0] == 'male'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting this?

1. Iterate over `dict`.
2. Keep height if `gender =='male'`.
3. Compute the average.

```
height_lst = [int(height) for name, (gender, height) in students.items() if gender == 'male']
print(f'Average: {sum(height_lst)/len(height_lst)}')
```

Output:`Average: 181.875`

You can correct `newDict` like the below:

```
>>> dict(filter(lambda elem: elem[1][0] == 'male',students.items()))

{'palii': ('male', '170'),
 'Minckach': ('male', '176'),
 'ddl': ('male', '180'),
 'Red1ska': ('male', '188'),
 'Sargeras': ('male', '185'),
 'Liah': ('male', '183'),
 'Leshega': ('male', '186'),
 'yurii': ('male', '187')}
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thanks for helping. Im tried to search this for hour)

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension to make a new dict including only males.

```
newDict = {k:v for k,v in students.items() if v[0] == 'male'}
```